# Version of the mongodb gorm plugin for grails 2.3.0?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I am using grails 2.3.0 and wanted to know which version of mongodb GORM is compatible with it.

The latest version of mongodb GORM requires 2.3.2 > http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb

My mongodb version currently is 2.6.0 but that should not matter I suppose.

It would be great If I could also know the gorm datastore dependencies version for grails 2.3.0 and mongodb gorm. Below are the ones for the latest mongo gorm.

```
dependencies {
   …
   compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.0.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.0.RELEASE'
   test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.0.RELEASE'
}
```

I also tried to go thru all the releases for mongodb gorm here: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/releases but did not get much of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Grails 2.3.11 app I'm using

```
compile ':mongodb:3.0.2'
```

before upgrade from 2.2.x to 2.3.x I was using `:mongodb:3.0.1`.

In another Grails 1.3.7 app I'm using `:mongodb:1.0.0.RC4` with some hacks to enable aggregation.

I tried to find a version of plugin in between to match my Grails version best, but it's not trivial. The branch names in github have nothing to do with released plugin versions.

BTW,

early versions of Grails 2.3.0 has severe problems (don't remember which ones exactly, but they made the upgrade from 2.2.x impossible). So, I'd recommend to upgrade your Grails to the most recent 2.3.11

Comment: Yes, totally agree that its not trivial to find out the exact matching version. I shall try upgrading my grails application.

Comment: Upgraded my grails app and it seemed to have worked.